# Sound steganography with `InverseSpectrogram`

Tags: fourier-analysis, sound, signal-processing, cryptography

Here is my code of how to hide a message inside a sound:

```
raster = Rasterize[
   Style["\n\n Hello World ", 100, FontTracking -> "Wide", 
    LineBreakWithin -> False]] // ColorNegate
audio = Audio[
   InverseSpectrogram[Graphics[Raster[Reverse[ImageData[raster]]]]]] //
   AudioNormalize
Spectrogram[audio]
```

> [image]
>
> `(*audio*)`
>
> [image]

I would like the audio to be of better quality and more pleasant to human ears (more musical). Also the sounds of single characters should be more distinct from each other.

For example you almost cannot distinguish sound of "o" from sound of "e" or sound of "d" by ears. How to achieve this?

Another question - How to specify the length of the audio? - I might want to have "Hello World" to be played over 1 second audio or over a 10 seconds audio.

Comment: You should read [this post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/917048) and use this [`ResourceFunction["SpectrogramEncode"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SpectrogramEncode). Try doing `SpectrogramEncode["Hello World!", 4000]`. If you lower the sample rate to around 10k then it's a bit more tolerable for the ear. You could also consider encoding using [SSTV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-scan_television) though it doesn't sound that nice. Or you could start with some music or notes via `SoundNote` and modulate that with the hidden message.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, `ResourceFunction["SpectrogramEncode"]["Hello World!", 4000,"Duration"->10]` lets you specify a "Duration", in this case it's 10s.